# R using rdist to generate results in a data table

Tags: r, data.table, distance, euclidean-distance

I am trying to speed up a calculation involving a distance matrix.
The following code snippet works in the script it came from, but is slow. It selects a particular country, year, and scenario combination, calculates MFAD, and writes the combination information, including the MFAD result and `rbind`s it to MFADHolder.

```
MFADHolder <- data.table(scenario = character(0), region_code.IMPACT159 = character(0), year = character(0), MFAD = numeric(0)) 
for (k in yearList) {           
  for (l in scenList) {         
    for (n in ctylist) {            
      dt <- dt.main[ year == k & scenario == l & region_code.IMPACT159 == n,]           
      itemlist <- unique(dt$IMPACT_code)            
      dt[,c("scenario", "region_code.IMPACT159", "year", "IMPACT_code") := NULL]            
      d <- as.data.table(rdist(dt))         
      data.table::setnames(d, old = names(d), new = itemlist)           
      MFAD <- sum(d)/20         
      newRow <- as.list(c(l,n,k,MFAD))          
      MFADHolder <- rbind(MFADHolder, newRow)           
    }           
  }         
}
```

Using Rstudio's new profiling tool, I found that the line

```
dt <- dt.main[ year == k & scenario == l & region_code.IMPACT159 == n,]
```

takes up the bulk of the computation time, presumably because of all the copying of the dt. I thought I'd be able to do it all within the data table. The line of code below could in principle replace all the code above, except it doesn't work.

```
dt.main[, MFAD := sum(rdist(dt.main[,!(c("scenario", "region_code.IMPACT159", "year", "IMPACT_code"))]))/20,
by = c("scenario", "year", "region_code.IMPACT159")]
```

The idea is to run `rdist` on just the relevant columns in dt.main, replacing the dt copy code above, then sum all the element in the distance matrix, divide by 20 and write all the results into the MFAD column.

When I run it, it never completes and R dies because my mac runs out of system memory and/or its hard drive runs out of space.

Here is complete code to demonstrate the problem

```
library(data.table)
library(fields) # needed for rdist function
dt.main <- readRDS("dt.main.rds")
dt.main[, MFAD := sum(rdist(dt.main[,!(c("scenario", "region_code.IMPACT159", "year", "nutrient"))]))/len.nutlist,
        by = c("scenario", "year", "region_code.IMPACT159")]
```

And here's a link to an RDS data file for testing - https://github.com/GeraldCNelson/nutmod/commit/c06b51478223bdc3226cccbe9498df0472a57465#diff-21615ea67b6aed07b31f6c21e89a810b

Comment: Could you please provide some exemplary data, so that the problem becomes reproducible.

Comment: are you sure your code is bug free? there seems to be no `IMPACT_code` but rather `nutrient`?

Comment: anyway is this what you are looking for? `system.time(dt.main[, `:=`(MFAD = sum(rdist(.SD)) / .N), by = c("scenario", "year", "region_code.IMPACT159"), .SDcols = cols])` mind the `.N` as I dont know what is `len.nutlist` and where `cols <- setdiff(colnames(dt.main), c("scenario", "region_code.IMPACT159", "year", "nutrient"))`

Answer (score 1):

John Smith's code was basically exactly what I needed, but didn't run as written.

The version below does and is extremely fast!

```
cols <- setdiff(colnames(dt.main), c("scenario", "region_code.IMPACT159", "year", "nutrient"))
system.time(dt.main[, `:=` (MFAD = sum(rdist(.SD)) / .N),
           by = c("scenario", "year", "region_code.IMPACT159"), .SDcols = cols])
```

Comment: that's because symbol '`' has a special meaning in text. glad it helped :)